# How can I open magit-status in a new frame if such a frame does not already exist?

Tags: spacemacs, magit

How can I open magit-status in a new frame? I've tried to write a custom function for this but it has some issues as described below.

```
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "gs"
    (lambda () (interactive)
      (when (not (string-prefix-p "magit:" (substring-no-properties (cdr (assoc 'name (frame-parameters))))))
        (select-frame (make-frame-command))
        )
      (magit-status)
      )
    )
```

I have the above code, however this opens 'multiple' frames if the above is executed multiple times. Is there a way I can prevent it from opening a new frame if an  existing magit frame already exists?

Is there possibly an alternative? Otherwise I'd imagine I'd need to get a list of all frames, search for the magit frame and select it.

Comment: I would imagine that Tarsius may already have something that does what you want.  If he does not, the following link contains a complex example of how to target a specific frame (and window within that frame) with a non-file-visiting-buffer and/or a file-visiting-buffer.  The best way to use that example is to have a function that creates/populates the target buffer without displaying it anywhere, and then use the `display-buffer-alist` and a custom function like in the linked example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Comment: I don’t have a full example, but I’d think customizing `magit-display-buffer-function` might be the way to go? https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Switching-Buffers.html#Switching-Buffers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following function as `magit-display-buffer-function`:

```
;; (require 'magit)

(defun magit-display-buffer-pop-up-frame (buffer)
  (if (with-current-buffer buffer (eq major-mode 'magit-status-mode))
      (display-buffer buffer
                      '((display-buffer-reuse-window
                         display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
                        (reusable-frames . t)))
    (magit-display-buffer-traditional buffer)))

(setq magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
```

This says, "If the to-be-displayed buffer is a Magit status buffer, first try to show a window in any frame that is already displaying that buffer.  If that fails, display the buffer in a new frame.  For non-status buffers, just use Magit's default behavior."

Comment: Do note two things: 1) if you use non-GUI emacs at all, this solution results in magit-status replacing the current buffer, which may or may not be what you want; and 2) that this solution won't work well if you use emacsclient from different endpoints, as it will re-use an available status window even if it's on a different display (or in a GUI when you're using SSH). I suggested `other-frame-window` because it handles this case correctly, as well as letting you explicitly choose.

Comment: This works for within emacs however, if trying to open via command line, it still seems to open multiple frames. For example via `emacsclient -c --eval '(magit-status)'`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Spacemacs, so hopefully you can apply this answer and let me know what modifications are necessary, and I can edit this answer so that it's applicable to both Spacemacs and other Emacs users.

The easiest way to achieve this in Emacs is to load the package [other-frame-window](https://github.com/emacsmirror/other-frame-window) (it's available using `list-packages` or `package-install`, which from reading docs seem to be readily available in Spacemacs).

In traditional Emacs, the `C-x 4` and `C-x 5` prefixes have been used to operate on windows and frames, respectively, but they're not easily extensible and they operate in a slightly unintuitive way, so `other-frame-window` attempts to address this by creating two new prefixes at `C-x 7` and `C-x 9`, both of which have the same following map, but the `C-x 7` commands operate on an (Emacs) window, and `C-x 9` on frames.

While it supports some built-in commands (which you can read about in the library's docs) for deleting windows/frames, moving them about, etc., the default thing it does when presented with an interactive command is to create a new window or frame and run the command in that new context. So, doing what you want is as simple as applying the following Elisp in your init file:

```
(other-frame-window-mode)
(define-key ofw-transient-map (kbd "z") #'magit-status)
```

Here, we first enable the OFW minor mode. (Since `other-frame-window` operates as a minor mode, you'll need to enable it — to start, simply executing `other-frame-window-mode` in the buffer you want to use will let you try it. You can run the command again to disable it.)

Then, we add `z` to the keyboard map to invoke `magit-status`. Once you do this, `C-x 9 z` will open Magit in another frame.

(`C-x 7 z`, will, obviously, open Magit in a new window, but that's relatively useless since that's the default behavior. This default behavior, by the way, is controlled by `magit-display-buffer-function` as was mentioned in [Michael's comment to your question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43641/how-can-i-open-magit-status-in-a-new-frame#comment66969_43641), but all the standard choices work on windows, not frames, and rigging up your own with this variable as suggested is rather difficult, and exactly the plumbing that `other-frame-window` takes care of for you.)

You could, of course, define a macro to do this directly without needing three keystrokes, or if you dip into the source code in `other-frame-window.el`, you can roll your own interactive function to do it directly.

Note that Magit will *not* dismiss upon pressing `q` in the case when it's the only buffer in the frame. That's because it's well-behaved and does a bury-buffer rather than kill-buffer, so that if the current frame happens to be the only frame, you won't accidentally kill Emacs. You *could* override this, but I'd advise against it. You can just kill the frame as usual, or use a prefix argument to `q` (in regular Emacs, that's `C-u q`) to force it to kill the buffer, frame and all.

One final remark: note that, in general, it's not a great idea to hand-write functions that unilaterally open new frames because there are many reasons why Emacs may be unable to do so — most notably, because you're operating in a non-GUI environment like a terminal emulator, SSH or Mosh session. Correctly-written frame-handling commands deal with this appropriately, so deferring this logic to `other-frame-window` seems like a good way to get the functionality you want without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: For some reason the code  "(define-key ofw-transient-map (kbd "z") #'magit-status)" does not work on my end. It hangs.